# обновлять сайт через битбакете

Tags: php, сервер, bitbucket

Мы хотим обновлять сайт через веб-сервис Bitbucket. Когда добавляем, то мерге делаем на Bitbucket. Хотим чтобы это как-то автоматически добавлялось на сервере.